# A Volume Shadow Copy Service operation failed. Unknown error (0x800423f0)

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, windows-server-backup

I have a pretty freshly installed SBS 2011, which backed up just fine right after I set it up.

After a couple of days, backup stopped working. Whenever I run it, I get the following error:

> Backup unsuccessful
>   A Volume Shadow Copy Service operation failed. Unknown error (0x800423f0)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is primarily connected with the [installation of the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Service Pack 1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94c5f178-f020-4d0f-ba7c-11c415d0d862/manually-running-psconfig-is-required-after-installing-sharepoint-foundation-2010-updates).

To fix this, perform the following steps:

> 1. Open an Administrative command prompt.
> 2. Change directory to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN`
> 3. Run `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures`

Comment: There are many updates and patches (SharePoint being the main culprit) which require you to 'inplace upgrade' VSS otherwise you'll find things breaking all the time. SharePoint, Backups, WSUS to name a few. On my SBS2011 install I've created a batch file to run the above command and have it on the desktop. After any update/upgrade or any part of troubleshooting an SBS problem I *always* run the inplace upgrade first. I've not noticed any ill effects from doing so (SBS is so broken anyway I probably wouldn't spot them).